Identify a CPU in a laptop
Is there a way of identifying a cpu on a laptop motherboard without booting it ?. I’m trying to tell if this is an i3,i5 or i7 cpu, but googling the number on it gives no results at all.


There are many methods, we just don't know what methods you have available. Armed with laptop brand and product number, you can usually figure out which CPU the laptop was manufactured with. Some manufacturers have a web page where you can type in the serial number and it will tell you the exact configuration it was sold with. I just can't figure out what's the electrical engineering part of this question.

Doesn’t work for the surface laptop, just shows it as a surface laptop 3

It's probably an i5-1035G7 (spec code SRGKJ - putting bits of the part's markings into your favourite search engine is generally a good place to start).
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/196592/intel-core-i51035g7-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-70-ghz/ordering.html
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/196592/intel-core-i51035g7-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-70-ghz/specifications.html

Thanks !, I didn’t notice that number, I was searching the long number
